# async.each calls callback not at the end

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async.js

I am using the `async.each` function to asynchronously fire off some I/O functions and want to use the optional callback feature to continue when *all* functions have finished doing their thing.

However, when running the example code below, one can see that this works fine, if the iterator is a synchronous function, but it doesn't seem to work with asynchronous functions. What am I doing wrong?

This example code should work in the browser console:

```js
function load (url, callback) {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.responseType = 'text';
  request.onload = callback;
  request.send();
}

// use async.each with an async function
async.each([1,2,3,4], function iterator(item, callback) {
    load("/", function onload() {
      console.log("inside async func: " + item.toString());
      callback();
    });
  }, function eachFinished(err) {
  console.log("each async func: end");
});

// use async.each with a sync function
async.each([1,2,3,4] , function iterator(item, callback){
  console.log("inside sync func: " + item.toString());
  callback();
  }, function eachFinished(err) {
    console.log("each sync func: end");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/async/1.4.0/async.js"></script>
```

This gives me the output:

```
"inside sync func: 1"
"inside sync func: 2"
"inside sync func: 3"
"inside sync func: 4"
"each sync func: end"
"inside async func: 1"
"each async func: end"
"inside async func: 2"
"inside async func: 3"
"inside async func: 4"
```

I would expect `"each async func: end"` to be called at the end ...

Comment: This typically happens if the first `callback()` is invoked with an error. Is this your actual code?

Comment: @Bergi Ah, yes, corrected that `responseType`. It's not my actual code, but more a minimal (not)-working-example. I could check for this error with changing the `eachFinish` callback to something like `function eachFinished(err) {if (!err) {console.log("each sync func: end");} else {console.log(err);}}` right? Still don't see any change :/

Comment: Yeah, that should do.

Comment: Hm, I cannot reproduce with this minimal code.

Comment: After quite some fuzzing around, I realized, that I wasn't using the release version of `async`, but the current master commit. Problem is not there in the 1.4 version. Should I answer my own question? Or delete it?

Comment: Answer it, I'd say. Though it's hard to believe that they commit code that fails this hard…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that I was using the current master commit and not the release version of async.js. Version 1.4.0 works just fine.